# Comparing possibly non-matching records in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a database table for a telephone billing system. Rates are matched by the longest prefix found, so that more specific rates can be used for certain numbers. Let's say the table looks like this:

| Column | Type |
| --- | --- |
| id | SERIAL |
| prefix | VARCHAR(15) |
| rate | DECIMAL(5,5) |
| startdate | DATE |

I'm importing rates from a new provider and need to prepare a report comparing the old rates to the new ones. This is pretty easy to do with a self-join based on the date:

```sql
SELECT t1.prefix, t1.rate AS old_rate, t2.rate AS new_rate, t2.rate - t1.rate AS diff
FROM (SELECT prefix, rate FROM testing WHERE startdate = "2020-01-01") t1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT prefix, rate FROM testing WHERE startdate = "2024-01-01") t2
  ON (t1.prefix = t2.prefix)
WHERE ABS(t1.rate - t2.rate) > 0;
```

Where this falls apart is that the prefixes of the old and new providers don't always line up so my join won't always pick up a matching record. For example, with these records:

| id | prefix | rate | startdate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1250 | 0.02 | 2020-01-01 |
| 2 | 1250208 | 0.03 | 2020-01-01 |
| 101 | 1250 | 0.01 | 2024-01-01 |

I want to see the rate for calls to numbers starting with 1-250 went down by 0.01, which is included in the result. But I also want to see that the rate for calls to numbers starting with 1-250-208 went down by 0.02.

Likewise, with these records:

| id | prefix | rate | startdate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 1604 | 0.01 | 2020-01-01 |
| 120 | 1604 | 0.02 | 2024-01-01 |
| 121 | 1604463 | 0.025 | 2024-01-01 |

I want to see that calls to 1-604 went up by 0.01 but also that calls to 1-604-463 went up by 0.015.

Note the numbers here are just examples; our rate tables have prefixes as long as 27861046247 (South Africa mobile) and as short as 790 (Russia mobile.)

How can I alter the `JOIN` (or is that the wrong approach?) to pull in the appropriate records in both directions? I'm not concerned about performance or getting everything in one query, as this is a one-time manual process.

Fiddle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a09780/2)

Comment: `ON t2.prefix LIKE t1.prefix + '%'` maybe? That only gets you cases when the prefix got longer not shorter, for that you would need to reverse the `LIKE`.

Comment: Is the problem focused on the _current_ rate for a given set of numbers?  Or on _how much the price went down_?  (The latter is probably more challenging to solve.)

Comment: @RickJames yes I need to know what the change in price (up or down) was across all records even when it's missing from the old set or the new.

Comment: Change from the earliest date to the latest?  Or maybe each incremental change?

Comment: @RickJames there are only 2 distinct start dates in the table, so change from old to new.

Comment: I see only 2 distinct start dates in the sample data, but I would assume there may be many more in the real data (either already or in the future).

Comment: @RickJames changing wholesale SIP providers is something we have done twice in the last 12 years and aim to avoid it when possible!

Comment: I suspect the output will have some bogus rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another right join t1 with t2 and use union to remove duplicated data.
You can write like this:

```
SELECT t1.prefix,
    t1.rate AS old_rate,
    t2.rate AS new_rate,
    t2.rate - t1.rate AS diff
FROM (
        SELECT prefix,
            rate
        FROM testing
        WHERE startdate = "2020-01-01"
    ) t1
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT prefix,
            rate
        FROM testing
        WHERE startdate = "2024-01-01"
    ) t2 ON (ON t1.prefix LIKE CONCAT(t2.prefix, '%'))
WHERE ABS(t1.rate - t2.rate) > 0
UNION
SELECT t2.prefix,
    t1.rate AS old_rate,
    t2.rate AS new_rate,
    t2.rate - t1.rate AS diff
FROM (
        SELECT prefix,
            rate
        FROM testing
        WHERE startdate = "2020-01-01"
    ) t1
    RIGHT JOIN (
        SELECT prefix,
            rate
        FROM testing
        WHERE startdate = "2024-01-01"
    ) t2 ON (ON t2.prefix LIKE CONCAT(t1.prefix, '%'))
WHERE ABS(t1.rate - t2.rate) > 0;
```

first join you get only data in the table (t1) but data that doesn't exist in ( t1) like 1604463, in this case, is in (t2) we can't get it that why we need another join from t2 to t1 (right join) now we have the result we need last thing is to merge these two result together why we add "union" for final result. and one more I think what you need here is to change the join condition based on your need.

Comment: This works for the given data, but the NA numbers were just an example. Could be any length. Also code-only answers are frowned upon here; adding explanation to your code helps others understand it better.

Comment: if it's a problem with the length you can change first from ON (substring(t1.prefix, 1, 4) = t2.prefix) to  join ON t1.prefix LIKE CONCAT(t2.prefix, '%') like https://stackoverflow.com/users/22764733/nekkanti-chakradhar mentioned and second join from (t1.prefix = substring(t2.prefix, 1, 4))  to ON t2.prefix LIKE CONCAT(t1.prefix, '%')

Comment: @miken32 here is the explanation: first join you get only data in the table (t1) but data that doesn't exist in ( t1) like 1604463, in this case, is in (t2) we can't get it that why we need another join from t2 to t1 (right join) now we have the result we need last thing is to merge these two result together why we add "union" for final result. and one more I think what you need here is to change the join condition based on your need.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work (though it takes 25 minutes to run through the 250k records; it could probably use an index.) I will accept this answer but first please [edit] your answer to: include a clear explanation *in the body of the answer*, incorporate the changes suggested in your comment, and clean up inconsistent syntax and casing.

Comment: The above community comment means your answer has been placed into review, this is often where code-only answers get deleted, and is why you should always add explanation to your answers.

Comment: @miken32 thanks. I'll add some explanation to the answer.